# Problem importing pymc3 in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror, pymc3

Importing `pymc3` in my jupyter notebook causes the following error:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'logsumexp'"
```

---

Here are some other package versions:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.7
- Numpy 1.17.0
- Matplotlib 3.0.3
- Pandas 0.23.4
- Scipy 1.5.1
- Scitkitlearn 0.23.1
- Statsmodels 0.11.1
- Theano 1.0.4

Trying other pymc3 didn't solved the problem

---

I did manage to import `logsumxp` this way:

```py
from pymc3.special import logsumexp
```

But when I import `Normal` the same way, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'xarray.core' has no attribute 'formatting_html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it already? For example with "pip install pymc3" (https://docs.pymc.io/) ?

For me, the imports don't work when using the **pymc3.special** module because it says, it does not exist.

Try "**from pymc3 import Normal**"

If you can't find a solution for your local jupyter notebook, you could alternatively simply use Google Collab to create and use your notebook there: https://colab.research.google.com/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did install it with pip install pymc3. And because it didnt't work in the first place, I also tried other versions (but that didnt work either). I also tried from pymc3 import normal with out the special part, but again, that didnt work. However, I restared my computer and somehow it works now - I have no idea why, but as long as it lasts thats ok :D Thank you very much anyway!